# Remove a class instance in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, memory-management, garbage-collection

I've read the notes on GC happening at an undetermined time after disconnecting any references by instance variables, but would the second line in the `delete` method be foolish, unnecessary or thorough?

```
class MyClass
  # new instances added to @@instances
  ...
  def delete
    @@instances.delete(self)
    self.instance_variables.each{|v| self.instance_variable_set(v,nil)}
  end

end
```

Comment: The second line is a comment. Comments are always foolish and unnecessary.

Comment: I'll edit to make it more clear. Welcome!

Comment: @Radek S: Comments are always foolish? As the kids these days say, you straight trippin'.

Comment: I don't care if it's a 2 year old comment from an Anon user, what a stupid thing to say, and what a pretentious manner. And who the hell voted him up? Comments foolish and unnecessary, I ask you..

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessary. If you really want to trigger GC, use `GC.start` or `ObjectSpace.garbage_collect`.

And because it can't be recommended often enough, once again:

http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/theFullyUpturnedBin.html

Comment: Is there a good test that you've setup an instance to be marked for GC?

Comment: It will be marked for GC if there are no references to it or if it falls out of scope.  You can test if it has fallen out of scope by calling `defined? my_instance` and it returns `nil`, then it will be collected.  If you have a reference to it that won't fall out of scope, you can just do this: `my_instance = nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The method `delete` executes in the scope of the instance that is being removed from the `@@instances` structure, hence it cannot be garbage collected. Something triggered that method to run, and that something is currently holding a reference to it, therefore it cannot be garbage collected until after the method has returned (and the reference to the object been cleared).

That being said, the second line is completely unnecessary. Even if one of the instance variables pointed back to the object itself the GC is clever enough to figure that out (or rather, it just ignores it since it's not a [reference counting collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)).

Don't try to manually manage memory, it will not pay off. Whether or not you clear the references to the objects in those instance variables the GC decides when they will be freed. If I interpret the idea of your code example correctly all references to the host object are cleared after `delete` has run, and in that case it doesn't matter if its instance variables are cleared too, the objects will be just as eligible for garbage collection either way. Objects are GC'ed when they are no longer reachable, it does not matter if other unreachable objects have references to them.